# Concurrency signing in HSM with LunaProvider throw CKR_DATA_INVALID

Tags: java, signature, hsm

When I concurrently attempt to sign with the same key inside the HSM, some signatures fail with the following error :
com.safenetinc.luna.exception.LunaCryptokiException: function 'C_Sign' returns 0x20 (CKR_DATA_INVALID)

With only one thread and one instance of my jar, I have no error. 
More threads I have more often the signatures fail.
**An important point, if I have 2 instances of only one thread each the issue also occurs.**

I'm using Luna JSP provider. 
The algo is SHA256withECDSA.

I tried also with token connection, but same result.
I check my timeout in crystoki.ini, failing occurs before the timeout.
Even with a Singleton for the keyStore, or for the privateKey I have the issue.

Thread generator:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    SpringApplication.run(DccHsmTest.class, args);


    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
      Multithreading object = new Multithreading();
      object.start();
    }
  }
```

```java
 private byte[] CHALLENGE = new byte[10000];

 public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      final HsmService hsmService = new HsmService();

      hsmKeyStore = hsmService.hsmKeyStore(hsmPartition, hsmPassword);

      PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) hsmKeyStore.getKey(aliasToRetrieve, password);

      while(sign(privateKey)){
        ...
      }

      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      ...
    }
  }

  private static boolean sign(PrivateKey privateKey)  {
    try {
      Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "LunaProvider");

      signature.initSign(privateKey);
      signature.update(CHALLENGE);

      signature.sign();
      return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      ...    
      return false;
    }
  }
```

HsmService

```java
@Service
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class HsmService {

  public KeyStore hsmKeyStore(String hsmPartition, String hsmPassword) throws
KeyStoreException,                                                                   CertificateException,                                                                       NoSuchAlgorithmException,                                                                       IOException {

    LunaProvider lunaProvider = new LunaProvider();
    Security.addProvider(lunaProvider);

    LunaSlotManager lunaSlotManager = LunaSlotManager.getInstance();
    lunaSlotManager.login(hsmPartition, hsmPassword);


    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Luna");
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    return keyStore;
  }
}
```

The error definition of CKR_DATA_INVALID is:
The plaintext input data to a cryptographic operation is invalid.

But I always pass the same input, sometimes it works.

The CKlog doesn't provide much details :
FINISign ***CKR_DATA_INVALID***(5811ms) {"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" }

Just seems to return a bad signature

Comment: Have you checked that your multi threaded code is not causing any contention , can you post that code instead of the single threaded code above.

Comment: The `CHALLENGE` static variable has a big, big data race condition as it's shared amongst the threads. Remove the `static` modifier and run the test again.

Comment: @Augusto it doesn't change anything. It shouldn't be a problem to have a static, it's just the value we are inserting in the signature, furthermore the issue is thrown by signature.sign(), not by the update()

Comment: Using the 'CKlog' PKCS#11 logging utility bundled with Luna middleware (or any other PKCS#11 logger) might help to reveal if problem is on the java side (cryptoki is getting invalid data) or on the cryptoki side (it fails when given correct data)...Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Finally a simple reboot sold the problem.
Now I have to find if this issue is due to a bad usage of the HSM on my code, or if it's due to tests from other developer(the HSM is used by other project)